# How to insert data in an existing dataframe as incremental load with record flag as U

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

For example- This is dataframe1 with full load as record flag I

```
X_coordinate     Y-Coordinate           Record_Flag
415541.1         7250068.501            I
415546.12        7250079.97             I
415551.096       7250091.44             I
```

dataframe2 with incremental load as record flag U / This dataframe will be truncated later on
After this every time new records will be fetched in df2, then will be added to df1 and later on df2 will be truncated.

```
X_Coordinate   Y_Coordinate       
415557.59     7250075.006       
415562.56     7250086.473       
415567.53     7250097.944
```

Final Data frame (Expected data)(Using Python)

```
X_coordinate       Y-Coordinate         Record_Flag
415541.1         7250068.501            U
415546.12        7250079.97             U
415551.096       7250091.44             U
415557.59        7250075.006            I
415562.56        7250086.473            I
415567.53        7250097.944            I
```

insert is okay , how to do the incremental load? with change in dataflag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have identical column names in `df1` and `df2` (which is not the case in your example), use:

```
out = pd.concat([df2.assign(Record_Flag='U'), df1])
```

Output:

```
   X_Coordinate  Y_Coordinate Record_Flag
0    415557.590   7250075.006           U
1    415562.560   7250086.473           U
2    415567.530   7250097.944           U
0    415541.100   7250068.501           I
1    415546.120   7250079.970           I
2    415551.096   7250091.440           I
```

Comment: sorry i think my way of questioning is not clear my bad
Say, there is only one Dataframe(df) , in that i am doing FULL LOAD with X_Coordinate and its values and Y_Coordinate with its value and RECORD_FLAG as inserted(I) all this in my 1st Attempt to insert values in df.
IN second time, its an Incremental LOad with same columns but different values , but the challenge here its that in Column RECORD_FLAG , i want to show my old records as U(Updated) and new records the 2nd time incremental records as (I) can you help me with this ?